# Can you run an AIC twice in a row?

Tags: aic, ecology

I came across [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0140196317301386) paper that seems to make a bunch of models, run an AIC, select the best models from that, then run the AIC again. Am I interpreting this correctly? And is that okay to do? Couldn't figure out how to upload the paper directly, but here is the passage. I believe they use this technique for two different analyses!

> We built models employing climate variables to predict changes
>   in pi~non vigor using a two-stage process employing additive
>   covariates. In the first stage, we sought to identify the period of
>   time (from yearte3 to yearte1) over which covariates were most
>   predictive of changes in vigor. This process consisted of building six
>   models per covariate (representing periods starting between one
>   and three years prior and lasting from one to three years) and
>   identifying the most supported (lowest-AICc) among models with
>   lower AICc than the null model. The null model at this stage
>   included only previous vigor, log-transformed density of trees, and
>   log-transformed mean root crown diameter.
>   In the second modeling stage, we built a set of models representing
>   all additive combinations of covariates. While most covariate
>   pairs were correlated, precipitation and warm- and coolseason
>   VPD had jrsj < 0.7 and could be combined in the same
>   models without the risks of multicollinearity. We assessed support
>   for models using AICC, where n equaled the number of points (84).
>   We generated parameter estimates across the model set using
>   model averaging following Burnham and Anderson (2002) via the
>   AICcmodavg package (Mazerolle, 2013). We assessed the ability of
>   models to accurately predict trends and changes in vigor using a
>   pseudo-R2 calculated from an ordinary least squares model in
>   which observed changes in vigor were predicted by modelaveraged
>   estimates of changes in vigor. Residual plots indicated
>   normality of within-plot error.We used the nlme package (Pinheiro
>   et al., 2013) to fit mixed models and we performed all modeling in R
>   (R Development Core Team, 2014).
>   2.4.3. Pinyon Jay plot use vs. non-use
>   To investigate the relationship between patterns of tree vigor
>   and the distribution of nesting Pinyon Jays, we first estimated
>   nesting colony boundaries within focal years in which intensive
>   nest-searches were conducted. We used a 95% minimum convex
>   polygon (MCP) around all nests detected in 2007, 2010, 2011, and
>   2012 via the adehabitatHR package (Calenge et al., 2015). The 95%
>   MCP excludes possible outliers to reduce inflation of MCPs (White
>   and Garrott, 1990). In addition to MCP area, we added a 100 m
>   buffer because we assumed birds selecting nest sites within colonies considered habitat quality in a larger area within which
>   fledglings may use habitat later in the season. This assumptionwas
>   supported by our observations of 10 recently-fledged broods within
>   this buffer area from 2005 to 2009. Within each of the four focal
>   years, we considered tree plots within colony boundaries to
>   represent areas of use and plots measured in the same year but not
>   within a colony boundary to be non-use areas.
>   We modeled use vs. non-use of plots using generalized linear
>   mixed-effects models with a binomial link. In each model, as in
>   models of trend and vigor change, the sampling plot was treated as
>   a random intercept nested within the sampling transect. Year was
>   included as a fixed effect to allow the modeling of annual variation
>   in the effect of vigor on plot use vs. non-use. Inclusion of year also
>   addressed annual variation in plot numbers (greater in later years;
>   Appendix 1) and the number of plots assigned to the “use” category
>   due to changes in the size and location of the nesting colony.
>   Finally, we sought to control for known patterns of nest-site selection
>   (in the immediate nest vicinity) in this species (Johnson
>   et al., 2014, 2015). We addressed these concerns by first determining
>   the best model without vigor as a predictor among models
>   having only interactions between year and non-vigor covariates
>   (density, height, and diameter).
>   Using the best model (lowest-AICc) from the preceding set as a
>   null model of non-vigor plot effects, we then constructed a final
>   candidate set (n ¼ 3 models) in which we added vigor and a vigor*
>   year interaction. We assessed the ability of these models to
>   discriminate used vs. non-used plots with the area under the
>   receiver operating curve (AUC), a threshold-independent index of
>   accuracy (Fielding and Bell,1997).We used the lme4 package (Bates
>   et al., 2015) to fit generalized linear mixed models.